# How to declare multiple function with meta programming in c++?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

How to declare multiple function with meta programming in c++?

I want to declare 100 functions to bind the python module like this.

```
int Func(string name, int a1);
int Func(string name, int a1, int a2);
int Func(string name, int a1, int a2, int a3);
int Func(string name, int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4);
....
```

It looks like a meta programming which use **#define**. But it is just my guess.
I didn't get any key idea for that.

For similar example, the boost::python::api::object has this declaration.

```
boost::python::api::object Func;
//Maybe boost will declare multiple functions use meta programming
Func(10, 20 ,30 );
```

How can i declare multiple functions overload like above?

Comment: Do you need 100 different definitions? Is there a common pattern you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Parameter pack(since C++11)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

```
template<class ... Types>
int Func(string name, Types... args) {}
```